# ArrayAdapter and ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have this line in my ListActivity

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MealsActivity.this, R.layout.meal_row);
```

and 2 of my layouts are like this:

```
<ListView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/android:list"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/android:empty"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="string/empty" />
```

meals_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:textSize="25sp" >

</TextView>
```

I believe smth is wrong with 'R.layout.meal_row' parameter.

```
 Process: mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories, PID: 2659
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
```

How do I specify textview in which data should be listed ?

Comment: you forgot to pass array in adapter...

Comment: "android:empty" in xml, is it valid way to define id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set custom adapter for array list..

```
//creating String Array
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>;
arraylist = "Your String Array";

//Creating adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.meals_row.xml, R.id.text, arraylist);

//setting adapter to string
list.setAdapter(adpt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Mind to add some explanation?

Comment: I think relativelayout is more suitable than textview, it just a suggestion

Comment: I meant to add some words in your answer. Code-only answers are little talkative.